# Softened water has a fishy smell

Tags: plumbing, water-softener

Background: inherited water softener system from family member (who elected to change to full house reverse osmosis), typical setup with resin tank and brine tank. Softener system sat for over a year, and the resin bed system was not replaced. Brine tank was dismantled and cleaned thoroughly.

Problem: prior to softener system installation, otherwise hard water had no “fishy” smell to it. Since installing the softener system, the softened water has a fishy smell, and seems more noticeable from the hot lines.

Additional info:

- family member setup was to treat well water, whereas my home is city supplied (although hard).
- family member setup also had charcoal filter as well as UV light installed; I did not install them, only the softener portion.
- performed system regeneration after install, cold softened water seemed ok but hot was still fishy… proceeded to drain the hot water tank (fairly new HW tank, no issues here), and refilled with new softened water (which seemed to have little to no fishy smell).
- a day later, and a regeneration later, fishy smell persists in both hot and cold lines.
- unsoftened city supply still no smell.

Questions:

- what could be causing the fishy smell, and
- what would you recommend to rid the system of said smell?
- Will continual regenerations every other day help?
- is a resin softener cleanser recommended? Add to brine tank? Is bleach just as useful, if so which brand should be used, and what are the precise steps recommended?

In hindsight I should have simply had the resin bed replaced to match my tested water condition (not yet tested).. so I do understand the fact that the resin tank sat for over a year may be a culprit for the smell. Would answers to the above be enough to help in the interim until water is tested pre- and post-softening to understand my supply condition and what the current softener is (or isn’t) doing? I’m planning to do so and replace the resin within the next few weeks.. but in the meantime can this be addressed, and is it even recommended to continue living with fishy-smelling water or simply bypass the softener altogether for now? I keep going back to resin tank having sat for a year and potential buildup of alien-like species.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's much of a downside to bypassing it until you figure this out.

Comment: Multiple sources claim you could sanitize the resin bed and tank with bleach. Brand does not matter, being plain and unscented does. I haven't really looked to see if anyone says it's a terrible idea, though I didn't trip across any such results in a quick scan. If you are going to replace the resin anyway, not much to lose there. Apparently there are also "resin cleaners" that may be more about mineral build up that hasn't flushed away, but might also help sanitize.

Comment: If you dont understand it, why are you picking and chosing on components.  A charcoal/carbon filter is often used to remove smells.

Comment: Don't use bleach on softener resin - the chlorine kills it. Some types can stand it better than others, but if you don't know which type you have, it could be an expensive mistake. Get a commercial resin cleaner.